# Создание DLL в Visual C++

Tags: c++, dll

Необходимо создать DLL-библиотеку в Visual C++. Есть исходные `.cpp` и `.h` файлы. В них содержится иерархия классов и соответственно и реализация. На этапе компоновки возникают ошибки плана

```
error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: virtual char * * __thiscall outpVar::NameListOut(int &)" (?NameListOut@outpVar@@UAEPAPADAAH@Z)" FuzzyLib.obj  Logic

error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall outpVar::outpVar(void)" (??0outpVar@@QAE@XZ) в функции "public: __thiscall SingleVar::SingleVar(char *,class polynom * *)" (??0SingleVar@@QAE@PADPAPAVpolynom@@@Z)    FuzzyLib.obj    Logic
```

С чем они могут быть связаны и как их можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `outpVar` затерялся, линковщик не может найти и ругается. Если он в основной программе — объявляйте как `extern`, если должно быть в библиотеке — ищите где забыли.